# Kafka consumer configuration to fetch at interval

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-camel, kafka-consumer-api

I am new to kafka and trying to understand various configuration properties I need to set for my  requirement as below.

I have a kafka consumer which is expected to fetch 'n' records at a time and after successfully processing them, another fetch should happen.

Example: If my consumer fetches 10 records at a time and every record takes 5 seconds to complete its processing, then after 50 seconds another fetch request should get executed and so on.

Considering the above example, Could anyone let me know what should be the values for the below configs ?

Below is my current configuration. After processing 10 records, it doesn't wait for minute as I configured. It keeps on fetching and polling.

fetchMaxBytes=50000       //approx size for 10 records

fetchWaitMaxMs=60000      //wait for a minute before a next fetch

requestTimeoutMs=         //default value

heartbeatIntervalMs=1000  //acknowledgement to avoid rebalancing

maxPollIntervalMs=60000   //assuming the processing takes one minute

maxPollRecords=10         //we need 10 records to be polled at once

sessionTimeoutMs=         //default value

I am using camel-kafka component to implement this.

It would be really great if someone could help me with this. Thanks Much.

Comment: You can understand these configurations more by reading their documentation [here](https://kafka.apache.org/26/documentation.html#consumerconfigs). And you will get an even better understanding of those configurations if play around with them in your application. Then you may show here on Stackoverflow what you have tried and what is not working.

Comment: Sure, updated the question with my current configuration

Comment: The fetch wait max is an upper bound, not a set number. Why does it matter if you put in a pause of the consumer or not?

Comment: Some of the records take more time to process. Assuming the average time complexity, need the consumer to hold on for a while(until the fetched records are completely processed) and then go for a next fetch.